# kotlin, got “Type mismatch. Required: Disposable? Found: Unit” when using observer object instance in the subscribe()

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, subscribe

Edit:

based on Dmitry Ikryanov's suggestion, 
using DisposableObserver will compile, but it causes crash

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.ProtocolViolationException: It is not allowed to 
subscribe with a(n) com.DataManager$theObserver$1 multiple times. Please 
create a fresh instance of com.DataManager$theObserver$1 and subscribe that 
to the target source instead.
```

the only code of subecribWith(), which has been called only once

```
fun initSession() {
    if (mDisposable != null && mDisposable!!.isDisposed) {
        mDisposable!!.dispose()
    }

    mDisposable = RxBus.listen(DataEvent::class.java).subscribeWith(theObserver)  <=== crash at here
}
```

the DisposableObserver is a member variable of the class:

```
var theObserver: DisposableObserver<DataEvent> = object : DisposableObserver<DataEvent>() {
    override fun onComplete() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: All Done!")        }

    override fun onNext(t: DataEvent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Next: " + t)
        onDataReady(t)        }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onError: ")
    }
}
```

===

Original question:

trying to use RxJava subscribe() in kotlin, get an error `“Type mismatch. Required: Disposable? Found: Unit”`, not sure what it means, anyone knows?

```
class DataEvent {}
```

using [RxBus](https://android.jlelse.eu/super-simple-event-bus-with-rxjava-and-kotlin-f1f969b21003)

```
object RxBus {

private val publisher = PublishSubject.create<Any>()

fun publish(event: Any) {
    publisher.onNext(event)
}

// Listen should return an Observable and not the publisher
// Using ofType we filter only events that match that class type
fun <T> listen(eventType: Class<T>): Observable<T> = publisher.ofType(eventType)

}
```

when call like this, it is ok:

```
mDisposable = RxBus.listen(DataEvent::class.java).subscribe({
        onDataReady(it)
    })
```

but when call the `RxBus.listen(DataEvent::class.java).subscribe(observer)` with defined `observer` instance
it shows red underline:  “Type mismatch. Required: Disposable? Found: Unit”

```
mDisposable = RxBus.listen(DataEvent::class.java).subscribe(observer)
```

the observer is:

```
var observer: Observer<DataEvent> = object : Observer<DataEvent> {
    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onSubscribe: ")
    }

    override fun onNext(@NonNull t: DataEvent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onNext: " + t)
        onDataReady(t)
    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onError: ")
    }

    override fun onComplete() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: All Done!")
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you sure that `initSession` called only once?

Comment: You are reusing the same instance of `DisposableObserver` which is not allowed. Don't save the instance in a field but create it for `subscribeWith`, just like Dmitry's example.

Comment: @akamokd, does it have to create a new DisposableObserver every time calling the subscribeWith()?   I am not sure what do you mean by "You are reusing the same instance of DisposableObserver", the `observer: Observer<DataEvent> = object : Observer<DataEvent>` is only used once in that subscribeWith().  @Dimity, yes the initSession is called only once.

Answer (score 4):

It's because in [RxJava 2.0](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html) method `subscribe(observer)` was changed and return nothing.

> Unlike the Observable of version 1.x, subscribe(Observer) does not allow external cancellation of a subscription and the Observer instance is expected to expose such capability.

You can use [`subscribeWith(observer)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribeWith-E-).
Example:

```
val disposable = Observable.just("Hello world!")
                .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<String>() {
                    public override fun onStart() {
                        println("Start!")
                    }

                    fun onNext(t: Int?) {
                        println(t)
                    }

                    override fun onError(t: Throwable) {
                        t.printStackTrace()
                    }

                    override fun onComplete() {
                        println("Done!")
                    }
                })
```

Comment: with `mDisposable = RxBus.listen(DataEvent::class.java).subscribeWith(observer)//subscribe(observer)`  the error becomes: ` Type inference failed, Expected type mismatch. Required: Disposable?. Found Observer<DataEvent>!`

Comment: Can you modify your question and add new code with `subscribeWith`?

Comment: I update the question, subscribeWith DisposableObserver compiles, but crashes.